# joining 3 table sql

Tags: sql

```
table A(a_id)
table B (b_id)
table c(c_id , b_id, a_id);


select a.*, b.* , c* 
from c join b
```

i'm confused from here ???

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
SELECT * FROM A 
INNER JOIN C 
ON A.a_id = C.a_id 
INNER JOIN B
ON B.b_id = C.b_id;
```

Comment: That's the only reasonable answer so far. With C being the bridge table, it seems rather obvious that the query is supposed to select A/B pairs. Nothing indicates that records shall be outer-joined to A or C.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c*  
FROM c
LEFT JOIN b USING (b_id)
LEFT JOIN a USING (a_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INNER`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `FULL`... **[JOINS](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm)** in following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.a_id = B.b_id
LEFT JOIN C ON B.b_id = C.c_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A.* from tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableC C ON C.a_id = A.a_id
LEFT JOIN tableB B ON C.b_id = B.b_id
```